# Analysis Limit Question Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $|r| < 1$.  Show that $$1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1 - r} $$ and find $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n)$

---

Does anyone have any idea on how to start this problem? I'm not sure what relevant material to look at for this exercise.

Comment: Hint: multiply both sides by $1-r$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

$1 - r^{n+1} = (1 - r) + (r - r^2) + (r^2 - r^3) + ...+ (r^n - r^{n+1}) = 1\cdot (1 - r) + r\cdot (1 - r) + r^2\cdot (1 - r) +...+ r^n\cdot (1 - r) = (1 + r + r^2 +...+ r^n)(1 - r)$, from this the answer of part a) follows.

As for part b), for $|r| < 1$, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} r^{n+1} = 0$. Thus:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1 - r} = \dfrac{1}{1 - r}$

Answer (score 0):

Since 
\begin{align}
1 + r + \cdots + r^{n} = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r}
\end{align}
can also be seen as
\begin{align}
\frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} r^{k}.
\end{align}
Taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ leads to
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^{k} = \frac{1}{1-r}.
\end{align}